# JVisualVM for Linux console?

Tags: java, visualvm

I need to be able to do some memory sampling on a VM that's running on a linux box that doesn't have any XWindows running.  I've tried to do it remotely but apparently JVisualVM does not support remote memory sampling.

What are my alternatives?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what type of sampling you want. `jmap` console tool (from JDK bin folder) allows some kind of memory dumping etc.

Comment: I want to be able to see the count of objects by class name

Answer (score 8):

You can use `jmap` to take a memory sample (aka a heap dump). The command below creates a file
`heap.hprof` in the current directory.

```
jmap -dump:format=b,file=heap.hprof <pid>
```

Once you have the sample you can transfer it to another machine for analysis with whatever tools you like. I recommend [Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/).

Answer (score 2):

setup a remote DISPLAY on your linux server and run jvisualvm such that the ui displays on your local xserver.  it might be slow, but it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Visual VM Basically a GUI Tool for Profiling, Taking Heap Dump, Thread Dump

**Option 1** - Use APM like Visual VM for Linux - You can try Glow root and Pack it in your Docker Image or Jar ,which starts agent

- Access the same via http:\>:4000\ should be able to profile

**Option 2**

- See if you can Access your Remote Server in Putty or SSH Tool
- Try to Get the Putty with SSH Tunnel Enabled to your Target Server
- Enable JMX Port in your Server
- Open Visual Vm From your Windows to Tunnel to item

[Reference to the Visual Vm to Kubernetes](https://gist.github.com/anderson-custodio/2345a6248355063d02da948c5c9ee480)

[SSH Tunnel to Visual VM](https://dresselhaus.biz/connect-java-visualvm-or-jconsole-via-ssh-tunnel/)

Answer (score -1):

Ubuntu uses command visualvm, and you can install it with: sudo apt install visualvm

Comment: OP does not have a XWindow running

Answer (score -5):

Path to your software :

[softwares/visualvm_14/bin] -> ll

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxxxxxx xx   6287 Dec 11 15:52 visualvm 
-rw-r--r-- 1 xxxxxxx xx 190464 Dec 11 15:52 visualvm.exe

1st file is for Lx OS
2nd file is for Windows OS
```

Command to start the application:

```
for Linux "jvisualvm"
for Windows "double click the .exe file"
```